# SSM doesnt allow me to edit a Datetimeoffset field in edit top 200

Tags: ssms, datetimeoffset

> SQLserver  version
>   Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.0.5500.0
>
> Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                       10.0.5500.0
>
> Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                        6.1.7601.17514
>
> Microsoft MSXML                        3.0 4.0 6.0
>
> Microsoft Internet Explorer                        9.0.8112.16421
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework                       2.0.50727.5456
>
> Operating System                       6.1.7601

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoles](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[FromDateTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
[ToDateTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL
```

I have a constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoles] ADD  CONSTRAINT   
[DF_UsersInRoles_FromDateTime]     
DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) FOR [FromDateTime]
```

which seems to work.
Edit 200 shows the values just fine.   I just can't edit them.

I get this error
   `The changed Value was not recognized as valid. .Net
 Framework type:DateTimeOffset Error Message:Offset must be specified> in whole minutes. Parameter Name: Offset`

I was trying to change the `date` or `time` and not the `offset`.
I can't even delete the value even though `NULLS` is allowed .

What am I doing wrong ? or Is this an SSMS bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a bug with the editor, very frustrating - see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/vstsdb/thread/4ea43c84-15c8-4f63-967f-6944f1d71660).